# Onclick Event Tracking Google Analytics Wordpress Visual Composer Plugin

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, google-analytics

I'd like to add this code for GA event tracking:

```
onclick="ga('send', 'event', { eventCategory: 'Contact', eventAction: 'ContactRequest'});"
```

on this Call To Action

```
<div class="vc_btn3-container vc_btn3-center vc_custom_1477135392137"><a class="vc_general vc_btn3 vc_btn3-size-md vc_btn3-shape-rounded vc_btn3-style-modern vc_btn3-block vc_btn3-color-grey" href="http://davidetaraborrelli.it/contatti/" title="" target="_blank">CONTATTAMI</a></div>
```

However, I don't know how to do it in Wordpress, my knowledge of coding are limited to coding a simple page from scratch, in that case I would simply have added the piece of code after HREF.

Since this page uses Visual Composer I don't know how to add that onclick piece of code to that div.

Any help is really appreciated, I hope it makes sense.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you want to add this tracking code on a CTA button in Visual Composer. There is this **Advanced on click action** option that Visual Composer provides. You can use that. It is fairly straight forward. Check out the following screenshot.

[image]

**EDIT:** This solution is tested on Visual Composer version **4.12**, may not work if you have an older version.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't see that option on my end. Maybe it has been removed?

Comment: The screenshot refers to the very latest version of the Visual Composer. Which version are you using?

Comment: I'm sorry, you're right. I wasn't on the latest version. Wordpress wasn't prompting for updates, that's why I missed it. For some reason, I had to update the whole theme before being able to update VC. It works perfectly now! Thank you so much for you're answer and solution, I really appreciated the time you dedicated to my issue. Thank you ron4ex!

Comment: You're welcome. Great that it worked. I've updated my answer mentioning the Visual Composer version, so it may help others.